# Is it possible that low encoding bitrate in ffmpeg generates low saturation?

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding

Is it possible that low encoding bitrate in ffmpeg generates low saturation? Or is encoding only related to artifacts like blocking or ringing?

Answer (score 0):

Lossy video encoding through techniques like DCT will introduce distortion in the frequency of data, but shouldn't affect the amplitude of that data.  At extreme levels of compression, this may not be true.

What this means is that colors may be smeared or less detailed, but the saturation level of color shouldn't change